# Save Facebook data with custom values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I trying to use login with Facebbok but I have trouble. I don't know how to do this:

1. User use Facebook Connect and accept website's application.
2. Next, user is redirected to form where he give username for my website.
3. Fetched Facebook data and username are saved in database.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

1. User use Facebook Connect.
2. Fetched Facebook data is saved to session.
3. User is redirected to form where is *name* input.
4. Form is sending request with data from session.